# Paste multiple strings onto one string

Tags: r, paste

I have a vector
`Names<-c("A", "B", "C")`

And I would ultimately like something like this
`c("A_Mean", "A_Median", "A_InGroupVar", "B_Mean", "B_Median", "B_InGroupVar", "C_Mean", "C_Median", "C_InGroupVar")`

I have tried the paste function
`c(paste(Names, "_Mean"), paste(Names, "_Median"), paste(Names, "_InGroupvar"))`

But I need the vector to be ordered by Name. I know I could easily do this in a loop but I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a raw approach:

```
Names <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=3)
Stats <- rep(c("Mean", "Median", "InGroupVar"), 3)
paste(Names, Stats, sep="_")
[1] "A_Mean"       "A_Median"     "A_InGroupVar" "B_Mean"       "B_Median"    
[6] "B_InGroupVar" "C_Mean"       "C_Median"     "C_InGroupVar"
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I was after! Seems so obvious now

Comment: You can also do this without having to call `rep` a second time. `paste0(Names, "_", c("Mean", "Median", "InGroupVar"))`

Comment: Sure, but I deliberately chose to show the different ways to use `rep`. But thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 3):

I like `sprintf` better for this particular problem:

```
Names <- c("A", "B", "C")

sprintf("%s_%s", 
        rep(Names, each = 3), 
        c("Mean", "Median", "InGroupVar"))
# [1] "A_Mean"       "A_Median"     "A_InGroupVar" "B_Mean"      
# [5] "B_Median"     "B_InGroupVar" "C_Mean"       "C_Median"    
# [9] "C_InGroupVar"
```

Alternatively, this also works, but gives you the results in a different order:

```
do.call(paste, 
        c(expand.grid(
          Names, c("Mean", "Median", "InGroupVar")), 
          sep = "_"))   
# [1] "A_Mean"       "B_Mean"       "C_Mean"       "A_Median"    
# [5] "B_Median"     "C_Median"     "A_InGroupVar" "B_InGroupVar"
# [9] "C_InGroupVar"
```